# How can I send and receive two types of data from one single field in firestore for flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

I have two textfields in my flutter app. I used showDatePicker on the first one when tapped and showTimePicker on the second one when tapped (to let a user choose a certain date and time).

I am using a class model to send and receive date and time both from one variable:

```
DateTime? taskDate; // Time as well
```

I thought about sending them separately but look what happens in firebase when I send them both together :

[image]

One timestamp field that has date and time seperated ( like a map).

My question is how can I point to one of them ( date or time) in Firestore so I can do some actions on them?

For example I want to add a task in 13 January 20203 and I want this to be saved in date field and the time to be saved in time field. What you see in the picture isn't picked date and time.

This is the code of sending data using a model and bloc state managment :

```
 TaskModel? taskModel;
  void addTask({
    required String title,
    required DateTime date,
  }) {
    emit(AddPostLoadingState());
    taskModel = TaskModel(
        taskTitle: title,
        taskDate: date,
        name: userModel!.name,
        uid: userModel!.uId);

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .add(taskModel!.toJson())
        .then((value) {
      getTask();
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error);
      emit(AddPostErrorState(error));
    });
  }
```

And since I know that datetime recieved as timestamp in firestore .. I changed it in the type when I get data :

```
void getTask() {
    emit(GetTaskLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('tasks')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uId)
        .orderBy('taskDate')
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      tasks = []; // Global List<TaskModel>
      for (var element in value.docs) {
    
        data['taskDate'] = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
            data['taskDate'].seconds * 1000);
      
        tasks.add(TaskModel.fromJson(data));
      }

      emit(GetTaskSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(GetTaskErrorState(error: error));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please include how exactly do you send the data to Firestore. Probably you need some conversion, Firestore timestamps are not the same as `DateTime` objects.

Comment: I just included the code of sending and recieving Peter .. All I want to know can I access date and time from one timestamp field in firestore. It's ok if you have another idea, I would appreciate that.

Comment: You can convert Firestore timestamp to Dart `DateTime` object calling `toDate()` on the data. The other way (from `DateTime` to Firestore timestamp) is `Timestamp.fromDate(..)`.

Comment: It's not about converting DateTime to Timestamp or vice versa, I already did it .. I want to reach to date and time in that field seperatly.. I want to choose a time and I want it to change in that time insied the timestamp field and I also want to do the same with date. is that possible?

Comment: I want to send date to that specific field and time as well and in the same time I want to retrieve from these specific fields I showed in the pic from firestore. Hope it's clear now,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore `Timestamp` field is an atomic value that contains both date and time. There is no way to set the date and time of the field separately, as it's stored as a single value in the database.

If you want to manipulate the date and time separate in the database, consider storing them as separate fields (e.g. in a map as you already describe) yourself. Then you'll need to convert to/from a `DateTime` in your code when reading from/writing to the database.

Comment: Thanks Frank .. so is it possible to save them as seperate Strings but get them as DateTime ..because I want to make a notification for example exactely in the same date and time picked by the user?

Comment: What is the best way to save date and time in firestore?

Comment: The best way depends on your use-case, as apparently you have found one where saving them as a timestamp is not working out for you. It's possible to save them separate and convert them to/from a `DateTime` as long as you write the code to do that mapping.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I sent them as separate String fields and when I needed them to be dates I converted them.